# How can I display non-editable view for the bamboo task

Tags: plugins, bamboo

It's possible to create user interface for Bamboo task configuration. According to [the documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/bamboo-tasks-api/writing-a-task-with-a-user-interface), I should provide `edit` and `view` template. In order to display a editable view you have to simply edit a task. But where and how can I display a result of a `view` template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Task's **view** mode was deprecated since Bamboo 5.13, so you can just ignore this resource

https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/5.14.1/com/atlassian/bamboo/task/AbstractTaskConfigurator.html#populateContextForView-java.util.Map-com.atlassian.bamboo.task.TaskDefinition-

Comment: But what about older versions of bamboo? Question is still relevant.

Comment: The same, looks like it was not used for a long time